# Hybrid App Development, Database-Driven Content

Tags: web, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I've been doing a lot of research, and perhaps just need a few dots connected.

I have an idea for a mobile app/website that contains lists of local eating/drinking establishments along with the deals/specials they offer each day. The idea is to create an app that people can refer to in order to save money on a night out.

I'm familiar enough with HTML/CSS/JS to create a functioning website, but when it comes to backend I'm a little confused. Editing the markup in order to reflect changes (e.g. a new deal starts or new establishment opens up) is a bit cumbersome. Now I know I want a database with my information ready to be displayed on my page. Does this mean that I need to develop my own API for everything, and then make sure it integrates with the hosting website that I end up choosing?

I feel like I'm missing something that should make it obvious what the next step is. Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you are exactly right.

The long answer is that is definetly one way to do it.   But, for large projext just using JS can get quite cumbersomoe on your client end.   Usually the first level would be using something like ajax. It's a great way to start and you can go a long way with just ajax. This is acutually where most people "start" when using just javascript to make api calls.   The next level would be to use a framework like Angular.   This will of course do more for you than just help handle api calls and it requires a larger investment in learning.

So that is all client side...

Now for the server side part...  When you publish a website you are now dealing with "server-side" content.  You have taken your static content and it is served up from the server but it's always the same static content from the server then it becomes dynamic on the client when all the javascript starts getting parsed.

The API is another server side component.  But instead of being static like your pages, a bunch of files just sitting there, it is an actual application on the server.  It takes a command via an api request and then does its thinking and then spits out a response object dynamically to the requester, which in this case will be the JS on your site.

Now, if you don't like the idea of learning to make your own API there are resources out there that will host an api for you and give you a gui to build your own API.  I can't recommend one because I have never used one, but I do work with businesses that do and they love the fact they don't have to hire a dev to make thier apis.    The downside is they are tied to that service and limited to the functionality that the service offers.  It's not a big limitation as the services are quire powerful but if you are going to be managing complex data sets then it would probably be better to learn to make your own api.

Hope that clears things up a bit for you!

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Let's say I have a front-end created and I've written my API back-end; on site-load, would I just grab all of the DB entries I need in order to populate my menus?

Comment: Short answer, yep.   Long answer, if the framework allows, it's always better to call the API once for those kind of calls and then keep that data there and just reload the page content.  Have you heard of the the idea of a SPA?  Single page app.   It looks to the user like multiple pages but its really a single page and just the content between the header and footer change.  Angular and React I believe are the two most popular frameworks for that kind of site.    Then you aren't calling to get your nav every single page call.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Pointing me in the right direction is a huge help. Coming from a scientific programming background I've been a bit lost with web-based work.